# Where does the child process start after call fork()?

Tags: c, unix, fork, exec

Accroding to the book named 'Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment', after we call `fork()`, child process call `exec()` to run a new process. `exec()` would use a new process to replace the old one, and the new one would start at `main()`.
But we all know, when we call `fork()`, both the father process and child process start at `fork()` function. So, how do we understand the book's opinion?

Comment: There might be some confusion. New process comes to existence with `fork()`. `exec()` replaces the program being run... but does not create or start new process. I suspect the term process might be used a bit loosely?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe their was some confusion in the wording of the book:

> • We call fork to create a new process, which is a copy of the caller.
>   We say that the caller is the parent and that the newly created
>   process is the child. Then fork returns the non-negative process ID of
>   the new child process to the parent, and returns 0 to the child.
>   Because fork creates a new process, we say that it is called once—by
>   the parent — but returns twice—in the parent and in the child.
>
> • In the child, we call execlp to execute the command that was read
>   from the standard input. This replaces the child process with the new
>   program file. The combination of fork followed by exec is called
>   spawning a new process on some operating systems. In the UNIX System,
>   the two parts are separated into individual functions. We’ll say a lot
>   more about these functions in Chapter 8.

On a successful `fork()` call, we return twice. Once as the **parent** process, and again as the **child**.

Calling `exec()` will change the program the process is running. This is often paired with the child process after calling `fork()`, but that is completely optional.

For simplicity, `fork()` creates (duplicates) processes, and `exec()` changes our processes.

[fork(2) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

[exec(3) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Comment: @Deduplicator:  From the POSIX standard:  *Conforming applications are recommended not to depend on vfork(), but to use fork() instead. The vfork() function may be withdrawn in a future version.*

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can go into the answer as well: There might be some confusion. New process comes to existence with fork(). exec() replaces the program being run... but does not create or start new process. I suspect the term process might be used a bit loosely? You can also refer to [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) man page for a clearer nomenclature and explanation:

> `execve()` executes the program pointed to by `filename`.  This causes the program that is currently being run by the calling process to be replaced with a new program, with newly initialized stack, heap, and (initialized and uninitialized) data segments.

Answer (score 0):

The `fork()` creates a child process by duplicating the calling process. The process that invoked `fork()` is the **parent process** and the newly created process is the **child process**. So, `fork()` splits a process in two, and returns `0` to the child process and the `PID` of the child process to the parent process, or `-1` if the fork failed.

The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces. At the time of `fork()` both memory spaces have the same content.

When you call `exec()` from a process, it runs an executable file in the context of an already existing process, replacing the previous executable. The new program is loaded into the same process address space. The current process is just turned into a new process and hence the `PID` is not changed, this is because we are **not creating a new process we are just replacing a process with another process** in exec.

There is concept called Copy-on-Write, its good to have knowledge about it-

> Copy-on-Write is an optimization where the page tables are set up so that the parent and child process start off sharing all of the same memory, and only the pages that are written to by either process are copied when needed.

If the process does not modify any memory and immediately executes a new process, replacing the address space entirely. Thus, it would be wasteful to copy all of the process's memory during a fork, and instead the copy-on-write technique is used.